# Largest Mass Diffraction

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

I have read "[Matter-wave interference with particles selected from a molecular library with masses exceeding 10000 amu](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8343)" which claims to observe diffraction patterns in objects of around 10'000 amu. *What is the largest mass objects shown to have diffraction patterns and show wave-particle duality?* I have heard a claims of this type have been shown for small amino acids, and possibly protein strands or even small viruses, but have struggled to find any references.

Comment: @oliversm, What is your question?

Comment: We generally recommend linking to the abstract page for arXive and journal articles instead of directly to the PDF. It gives other users a chance to read the abstract and examine the meta data before deciding if they want to download the whole thing. And while the size of the download isn't too bad for a six page paper, these links sometimes go to papers that are many tens of pages long.

Comment: Strictly speaking nothing shows wave-particle duality, but absolutely every piece of matter shows quantum properties just by being stable. The limits we can give for spatially coherent states are determined by the effective temperature scale at which we can measure. I think your best bet with regards to this may be the question what the longest wavelength phonons in solids are that have been resolved. Another good question may be what the effective recoil mass in Moessbauer spectroscopy is. I don't have numbers, but my gut tells me it's far larger than in direct molecular experiments.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this website](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles), photons, electrons, atoms, and some molecules, including [buckyballs](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0110012), have displayed wave-particle duality. [Here](https://vcq.quantum.at/fileadmin/Publications/2003-17.pdf) is a paper that talks about some of the experimentation for larger molecules. [This paper](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v2/n4/full/ncomms1263.html) talks about molecules with over 6,000 amu showing a wave-particle duality, and [this article](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/physicists-smash-record-for-wave-particle-duality-462c39db8e7b#.xdi3hp4s5) talks about the discoveries behind your paper. The article was written at the end of 2013, and it calls it a broken record. Everything I've looked at says this is the record. Interestingly, I did find a few sources (like [this one](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=25069)) that said scientists have tested molecules with a mass over 10,000 amu; obviously, it could be that better experimental equipment will allow this to happen.

In reference to amino acids/DNA/viruses: The mass of the DNA strand Enterobacteria Phage T4 is roughly 40,000 amu. The mass of a DNA strand only makes up a small component of the mass of a virus, so I highly doubt that either DNA or viruses show their wave-particle duality (see [this website](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-largest-structure-to-display-particle-wave-duality)). However, it should be mentioned that viruses are within an order of magnitude of 10,000 amu (100,000 amu).

I'll keep looking for information. Hope this helps!

Comment: Frankly, unless you link to a paper on a experiment that used bigger structure than the one the question references, then you really haven't answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, up to now, that is the paper showing the largest-mass particle interference experiment. The possibility of using larger particles, like small viruses and other kinds of biomaterials are discussed in this paper:

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/91/6/063007/meta

This is the most up to date reference I can find on the topic.

There is also a recent blog post here that is relevant and might be of interest to you:

https://thiscondensedlife.wordpress.com/2016/06/24/schrodingers-cat-and-macroscopic-quantum-mechanics/

Answer (score 2):

According to http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/mossfe.html it takes 200,000 iron nuclei to preserve the natural line width of the 57Fe transition used in Moessbauer spectroscopy, so that gets you to approx. 11 million AU of coherently moving mass. I don't know if one can do better than this with phonon spectroscopy, but it might be possible.

Comment: Underrated answer