# Will the wave nature of particles produce diffraction and interference effects

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

We know that the common objects (ball, human beings etc.) around us have de Broglie wavelengths either too large (mass is large and velocity is negligible) or too small (when velocity is  large enough).

While solving a numerical problem, I found that a body of mass 1 microgram moving with velocity $6.626 ×10^{-13} m/s$ (which is very small!!) will possess a wavelength of $10^{-12} m$ which is nearly same as that of high energy electron beams.

Then will that body show wave nature like that of electrons such as interference, diffraction etc?  Please explain.

Comment: have a look at this https://books.google.gr/books?id=FKDIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PP7&lpg=PP7&dq=wave+nature+and+nanoparticles&source=bl&ots=pCWROM06vM&sig=7FUNmDt6nF9ZTEfHwdU_QVnuedc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj86rKAmuXWAhWFChoKHQGTAZQQ6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q=wave%20nature%20and%20nanoparticles&f=false

Comment: This should interest you : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270588/154997

Comment: See for instance [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8343).  The masses they are talking about are still much lower than a microgram, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the beam of such particles will exhibit interference and diffraction if you take slits of width of the order of its wavelength.

Comment: and for the specific example wait a few hours and have a very very clean vacuum.